# Which are all the verb tenses where we cannot use the modal verb "can"?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

I know there are some tenses where we mustn't use **"can"**, instead of that we must use **"be able to"** like these sentences:

- They won't be able to play
- I haven't been able to sell it

Are there more cases where we cannot use "can"? Which **are all the verb tenses** where we cannot use it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should change this question and ask something way more  specific or interesting; a list of those words will never be exhaustive.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, not because I don't think it's too broad (I think it's a little too broad when we want to exhaust all possible cases), but because a) I believe that we can have a summary of useful and common cases, which would be useful for most learners, and b) it looks like we already have one such answer.

Comment: Also related (for *be able to* on a specific occasion in the past): ['managed to' vs. 'could'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44634/3281).

Comment: OK, I can make one more complete question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume you mean *tense* in the ordinary “layman’s” sense which includes all the verb constructions rather than one of the narrower technical senses in which the word is used by linguists.)

*Can*, like all the other English full modals, is “defective”: it is employed only in two finite forms, and has no infinitive or participial forms. Consequently, it can only appear as the **first** verb in a construction (<sup>∗</sup> marks unacceptable utterances):

- It cannot appear as an infinitive following another modal or in an infinitival clause:

  > <sup>∗</sup> I will can do that. → <sup>ok</sup>I will be able to do that.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> I want to can do that. → <sup>ok</sup>I want to be able to do that.
- It cannot appear as a past participle following *HAVE* in a perfect construction:

  > <sup>∗</sup> I have canned do that. → <sup>ok</sup>I have been able to do that.
- It cannot appear as a gerund-participle:

  > <sup>∗</sup> Canning do so, I left. → <sup>ok</sup>Being able to do so, I left.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> Canning do that takes study. → <sup>ok</sup>Being able to do that takes study.

  (It also cannot appear following *BE* in the progressive construction, but neither can *be able to*, ordinarily, because the sense of both is stative:

  > <sup>∗</sup> I am canning do that. → <sup>∗</sup> I am being able to do that.
- And of course no modal verb or semi-modal verb construction can appear in the passive, because these are all intransitive:

  > <sup>∗</sup> I was canned. → <sup>∗</sup>I was been able.

*Can* has one quirk which it does not share with the other full modals: the modal perfect *can have done* ordinarily appears only in the negative, or (very rarely) as an emphatic contradicting a preceding negative:

> <sup>∗</sup> He can have finished already.  *but*
>   <sup>ok</sup>He cannot have finished already. *and*
>   <sup>ok</sup>Not so: he **can** have finished already, and has done so!

Comment: +1 Nice post - very helpful for learners. But.. Hmmm, how about: "*The activity can have already commenced when the application is made, or it can be made prior to the company conducting the activity outside Australia.*"  or [some examples on these pages here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22can+have+already%22&oq=%22can+have+already%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6342j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22can+have+already%22&start=20)?

Comment: @Araucaria Anything can happen--or can have happened. But it's very rare: [*may* is about 500 times more likely there](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+have+already%2Fmay+have+already&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28can%20have%20already%20/%20may%20have%20already%29%3B%2Cc0). Note, too, that it's almost impossible in the core (non-modal) sense replaceable by *is able to*. ... But, yeah: this is why I gave up on writing a Canonical Post on modals!

Comment: Although the question asks mainly about *can*, the OP (and the future readers) may also want to read about *could* and *managed to*, and may find [this related post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44634/3281) useful.

Answer (score 1):

The modal verbs can only be used in present tense and in past tense. They have no infinitive and no past participle as normal verbs. So you can form no will-future or a conditional form with would. And you can't form perfect tenses.

"must" is normally used only in present tense. The use of must (past tense) is restricted to special cases.